# Eviction and Preemption: Pod Deleted or Just Killed?

Tags: kubernetes

I'm having trouble understanding what pod Eviction means mechanically in terms of K8s's actions -- what exactly does K8s do with the pod during eviction?

Specifically, my main question is this:
Under what conditions is an Evicted pod actually deleted from ETCD?
Under what conditions is an Evicted pod just killed without being deleted from the API server?

If I Evict a pod directly using the Eviction API, the pod object is actually deleted.
On the other hand, I've definitely seen pods hang in "Evicted" in the status column after I run "kubectl get pod".

Edit:
Removed follow-up questions about Preemption and OOM-Killing to conform to the guideline of one question per post.
Might post a separate question about OOM management later.

Comment: StackOverflow rules say that you can only have one question per post. Can you split this into multiple questions, please? Otherwise, it may be closed.

Comment: Reduced to just the question about conditions under which Evicted pod objects are deleted.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm also confused by this lately. Here are some findings after a while of digging in the source code and the docs.

'Eviction' here actually means two slightly different concepts, which are both documented in the official docs: [Node-Pressure Eviction](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/scheduling-eviction/node-pressure-eviction) and [API-Initiated Eviction](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/scheduling-eviction/api-eviction). They can really be mixed up when we just talk about 'Eviction' because they both do the same thing: evict pods from nodes.

Actually the doc of 'Node-Pressure Eviction' states:

> Node-pressure eviction is not the same as API-initiated eviction.

The difference between these two is that 'API-Initiated Eviction' is, as the doc said:

> performing a policy-controlled DELETE operation on the Pod.

So it will eventually delete the object stored in API server if the pod is evicted.

But 'Node-Pressure Eviction' is issued directly by the kubelet and what it does is set the PodPhase in pod's status to 'Failed' and the Reason to 'Evicted'

> During a node-pressure eviction, the kubelet sets the PodPhase for the selected pods to Failed. This terminates the pods.

This will result in the `Evicted` pods shown when running `kubectl get pod`.

So the direct answer to your question is:
If the pod is evicted using the Eviction API, the pod object will be deleted.
If the pod is evicted by kubelet due to node pressure, the pod object will remain and will be in Failed status.

Comment: Thank you, that clears things up completely!

Answer (score 2):

**Eviction**:

As per this [doc](https://sysdig.com/blog/kubernetes-pod-evicted/) authored by Javier Martinez

> Eviction is a process where a Pod assigned to a Node is asked for
> termination. One of the most common cases in Kubernetes is Preemption,
> where in order to schedule a new Pod in a Node with limited resources,
> another Pod needs to be terminated to leave resources to the first
> one.
>
> You can request eviction by calling the [Eviction API](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.25/#create-eviction-pod-v1-core) directly, or
> programmatically using a client of the API server, like the kubectl
> drain command. This creates an Eviction object, which causes the API
> server to terminate the Pod.Kubernetes Eviction API.

A common occurrence is the deletion of a pod by an end user. This indicates that the pod will be deleted from the Kubernetes control plane and ETCD.

Eviction happens if resource consumption by the pod exceeds the limit and kubelet triggers eviction of the pod or a user performs kubectl drain or manually invoking the eviction API. It's generally not not a normal activity

**Preemption**:

Preemption is the process of terminating Pods with lower Priority so that Pods with higher Priority can schedule on Nodes.

Preemption is the following process: if a new Pod needs to be scheduled but doesn’t have any suitable Node with enough resources, then kube-scheduler will check if by evicting (terminating) some Pods with lower priority the new Pod can be part of that Node.

As per this official [doc](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/scheduling-eviction/node-pressure-eviction/#node-oom-behavior) when you reach that configured limit, you get OOMKilled (out-of-memory) and will get restarted.

> If the kubelet can't reclaim memory before a node experiences OOM, the
> oom_killer calculates an oom_score based on the percentage of memory
> it's using on the node, and then adds the oom_score_adj to get an
> effective oom_score for each container. It then kills the container
> with the highest score.
>
> This means that containers in low QoS pods that consume a large amount
> of memory relative to their scheduling requests are killed first.
> Unlike pod eviction, if a container is OOM killed, the kubelet can
> restart it based on its RestartPolicy

You can also refer to this [doc](https://mihai-albert.com/author/mihaialbert/) written by Mihai Albert for more information about OOM killed and pod evictions.

Comment: @ Dmitri Gekhtman  I hope the above information clarifies your queries. Could you please let me know if you have any additional queries and I am happy to assist further.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation and references! It doesn't quite answer my questions --
My main question was "under what conditions is a pod API object deleted during eviction"?

It seems like either the pod object can be deleted during eviction OR the pod object can hang around in Failed phase with Evicted reason. I'm trying understand under what conditions either of these circumstances would happen.

Comment: The OP question requires a more detailed explanation, not just a conceptual explanation of eviction and preemption.

Answer (score 2):

Responding your first question
**"What exactly does K8s do with the pod during eviction?"**

By definition eviction is the process where a pod belonging to a node is asked for termination.
Evicted pods are terminated due to lack of resources.
Preemption is strongly tied to eviction, since when scheduling a new pod in a node with not enough resources another pod needs to be terminated to release the resources to the new pod.

For sake of stability Kubernetes is constantly checking resources and evicting pods, this is well known as node pressure eviction.

Kube-scheduler runs in control plane. Pod will start in Pending state until a matching node is found.

**1. Preemption eviction.**

The process of assigning a Pod to a Node follows the sequence:

**Filtering**

kube-scheduler will select all Nodes where the current Pod might be placed. Features like Taints and Tolerations will be taken into account here. Once finished, it will have a list of suitable Nodes for that Pod.
Scoring

**Scoring**

kube-scheduler will take the resulting list from the previous step and assign a score to each of the nodes. This way, candidate nodes are ordered from most suitable to least

**Pod priority**

When there are not available nodes for a pod to run, Kubernetes starts preemption process,evicting lower priority Pods

**2. Node-pressure eviction**

Kubernetes constantly checks node resources. ie.disk pressure,CPU,memory.
When those respurces reaches a specific threshold,pods will evict in order to free up the resource. Quality of Service is considered to determine the eviction order.
QOS classes deifine how pods are evicted in case of lack of resources.

With regards to your second question, **"Under what conditions is an Evicted pod actually deleted from ETCD?"**

Sometimes evicted pods are not automatically deleted from ETCD and kubernetes control plane. Unless there is a higher level controller such as deployment, daemonset, statefulset etc the evicted pod will not be created again and scheduled to a kubernetes worker node.

Try use delete instead of evict. Evict is more risky than delete because eviction could lead to a broken state if controllers such as deployment does not set to ready and/or an evicted pod has a large termination period

Related to your third question, **"Under what conditions is an Evicted pod just killed without being deleted from the API server?"**

Already responded above (first response).

Hope this gives you more insight.

Comment: Thanks, this is helpful!

"Sometimes evicted pods are not automatically deleted from ETCD and kubernetes control plane."

I wonder if anyone knows more about how the "Sometimes" works.